# When I try to drag and drop one of the <li>'s to another location with it's parent <ul> it disappears from the display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to get drag and drop to work correctly in that I have the following assigned to all the `<li>` tags:

```
$('li').draggable( {
    containment: $selMemContainer,
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: $selMemContainer
  } );
```

When I try to drag and drop one of the `<li>`'s to another location with it's parent `<ul>` it disappears from the display but still occupies the original location when looking within firebug but now has left and top values within the style definition (see below).  You can see that I tried to move `<li>` item 1,2 and 4 and if I get rid of the left and top values within firebug then the `<li>` reappears within the browser.
How can I get drag and drop to work correctly.

```
<div id="selMembersContainerDiverFieldAdmin2Photographs" class="membersContainer selMembersContainer" style="height: 351px;">
    <ul>
        <li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: -1237px; top: -309px;">
        <li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: -1237px; top: -353px;">
        <li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        <li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: -1237px; top: -441px;">
        <li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        <li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) instead of draggable. Sortable makes the element drag and contains them to the list. You are also allowed to drag between lists.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sEJTR/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the `li` tags, but it may be not a problem at all but it should be

```
<li class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: -1237px; top: -309px;"></li>
```

every `<li>` needs a closing tag, i.e.

```
<li>Something</li>
```

You are using `snap: $selMemContainer` that looks like a problem, to help you find out the problem here is a working example

**HTML**

```
<div id="selMembersContainerDiverFieldAdmin2Photographs" class="membersContainer selMembersContainer">
    <ul id="myUl">
        <li>Something</li>
        <li>Something Else</li>
        <li>Something More</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var $selMemContainer=$('#selMembersContainerDiverFieldAdmin2Photographs');
    $('li').draggable( {
        containment: $selMemContainer,
        cursor: 'move',
        snap:true
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HnErn/2/).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get drag and drop to work correctly

This does not tell us much what you are exactly expecting.

Using just draggable makes your items draggable. This is simply achieved by the default use:

```
var $selMemContainer = $(".selMembersContainer");    
$('li').draggable();​
```

This allows you to move the items around the screen now.

However, if you are trying to achieve to move items around within the `ul` you need sortable.

Basic sortable functionality looks like this (assigning id of sortable to the ul):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/vCsPM/) - Basic draggable items and a basic sortable list

As mentioned above, it is not very clear what exactly it is you are trying achieve. The above should get you started and if you have any more problems feel free to elaborate.

#### Additional Resources

- [**Draggable example and documentation**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)
- [**Sortable Example and documentation**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable)